# Reading CSV with multiple tables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to read data from a CSV that has several tables in. It looks like below and I would like to have Table 1, Table 2 and Table 3 separately.

```
TABLE1;START DATE(Y/M/D);START TIME;END DATE(Y/M/D);FINISHED;NUML;NUMD
1;2018/07/25;08:36;2018/07/26;true;3;2
2;2018/07/26;08:37;2018/07/27;false;2;0


TABLE2;CYCLE;DATE(Y/M/D);TIME;ACTIVITY;TYPE;DURATION
1;1;2018/07/25;08:44;3;d;2:41:20
2;1;2018/07/25;11:38;0;d;20:58:15
3;2;2018/07/26;08:45;3;d;2:41:20
4;2;2018/07/26;11:39;0;d;7:23:00


TABLE3;CYCLE;DATE(Y/M/D);TIME;QUANTITY;TYPE
1;1;2018/07/25;12:12;100;Water
```

At the moment I am trying to read the CSV with

`d3.dsv(';', 'testData.csv').then(data => {console.log(csvCycles);
});`

This reads it as one CSV so I have tried to separate it manually with a for loop that checks for the titles but then I just get things like 'TABLE1':'TABLE2' which is no use.

Does anyone know how I can do what I am trying to do?

EDIT: Here's the code I used the for loop in

`

```
d3.dsv(';', 'testData.csv').then(data => {
    let csvCycles = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        if (data[index]['TABLE1'] != 'TABLE2') {
            csvCycles.push(data[index])
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(csvCycles);
});
```

`

Comment: Not familiar with `dsv`, first thing I'd do is check if it has something to handle tables. I'd also post the code that got you the table titles so people can see how that works.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example, not sure which version of D3 you are using but this can be achieved by using [d3-dsv](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv) to parse CSV files and [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) to fetch text,

```js
// d3.text('multi.csv').then((data) => {
    var data = `TABLE1;START DATE(Y/M/D);START TIME;END DATE(Y/M/D);FINISHED;NUML;NUMD
1;2018/07/25;08:36;2018/07/26;true;3;2
2;2018/07/26;08:37;2018/07/27;false;2;0


TABLE2;CYCLE;DATE(Y/M/D);TIME;ACTIVITY;TYPE;DURATION
1;1;2018/07/25;08:44;3;d;2:41:20
2;1;2018/07/25;11:38;0;d;20:58:15
3;2;2018/07/26;08:45;3;d;2:41:20
4;2;2018/07/26;11:39;0;d;7:23:00


TABLE3;CYCLE;DATE(Y/M/D);TIME;QUANTITY;TYPE
1;1;2018/07/25;12:12;100;Water`;

    parsedText = data.split("\n\n");
    parsedText.forEach(element => {
      console.log(d3.csvParse(element, ""));
    });
  // });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Learning D3 Js</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "chart"></div>
<div id = "graphic"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dsv.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-fetch.v1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note** that I commented out the fetch and used data variable.